# Rationale behind Conditional Proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, natural-deduction

For some time now, I have been able to use the Conditional Proof rule in Natural Deduction. We assume A, derive B within the scope of the assumption and discharge the assumption to get that A implies B. This is, I believe, the syntactic approach to the proof, pure rule-based. However, what is the motivation behind this rule? In other words, why do we take it to be A implies B and not, say, A and B, or, other truth-functions?

One suggestion may be that we take the implication truth-function because we have assumed A to be true and B to be true too if A is true, which defines the implication truth-function. But it is not clear to me if in a formal proof of validity where we have to derive the conclusion using pre-established rules only, we are allowed to conceive that the formulas in the proof have truth values.

I am might be making some mistake at some fundamental level. If so, where have I gone wrong? Please help me clarify my doubts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Conditional Proof is: assume the truth of premise A and derive conclusion B. This amounts to saying that "if A, then B" holds.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can we consider formulas in a proof to have truth-values? Isn't a proof a purely rule-based affair of deriving formulas from other formulas using pre-established rules of inference?

Comment: Note that we do not know anything about the truth of $B$ if $A$ is false. All we can say is that if $A$ holds , then also $B$ Therefore "A and B" is not the same , in this case , we must be sure that $A$ is actually true which we however usually do not know in a conditional-proof.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that a formal proof, and any of its individual rule applications, is a purely syntactical object. Indeed, that is the very point of using a formal language with formal rules: they allow you to ‘figure things out’ by mere symbol manipulation.

Indeed, the symbols do not by themselves mean anything. For all we know, the $A$’s and $B$’s stand for fruits, and the $\to$’s and $\land$’s for operation on those fruits, like putting them together in a fruit salad. However, if we *do* look at these symbols as representing sentences with a truth-value, then we’ll find that the inference rules reflect what we consider logically valid inference principles. Therefore, a formal derivation of $B$ that starts with assumption $A$ means that $B$ logically follows from $A$, which we can symbolize as a conditional $A \to B$. In other words: yes, a proof is all ‘just’ purely syntactical, but they ‘mirror’ meaningful inferences.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: @SayanSarkar You’re welcome! :)

Comment: An issue though: are we to look at each A and each B, etc as standing for sentences with truth values? Or do we look at each entire line as standing for a sentence?

Comment: @SayanSarkar Both. $A$ is a sentence, $B$ is a sentence, $A\to B$ is a sentence, etc.

Comment: We have to assign truth values to the A's and B's first and then work out the truth values of the compound statements, right?

Comment: @SayanSarkar Exactly. It is assumed that the truth-value of the compound statements is a function of the truth-values of the atomic statements. That’s why it is called truth-functional logic.

Comment: Does it mean we have to construct truth tables for the A's and B's?

Comment: @SayanSarkar The truth-tables show how the truth-values of compound statements are a function of the truth-values of the atomic statements. But they don’t explain or justify why or when an atomic statement itself is true or false. So it makes little sense to have a truth-table for $A$.

Comment: You mentioned in the answer that we can see symbols as representing sentences with a truth value... Can any symbol represent any sentence with a truth value, regardless of whether the value of the sentence is T or F, or are there any restrictions regarding the same?

Comment: @SayanSarkar I think it would be hard to see the operator symbols as sentences ... you'd need to come up with some really perverse syntax-to-semantics parsing to make that consistently work.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we take it to be A implies B and not, say, A and B, or, other
> truth-functions?

We want to rule out the possibility that both $A$ is true and $B$ is false $\neg (A \land \neg B)$ which is often used to define logical implication:

$~~~~~~~A\implies B~~\equiv \neg(A \land \neg B)$

From this definition, we can derive the truth table:

[image]

[image]

Note that when $A$ is false, $A\implies B$ is true regardless of the truth value of $B$. This is the so-called *Principle of Vacuous Truth*.

Compare with the truth table for $A\land B$:

[image]

It agrees with the above truth tables only when $A$ is true.